# Как сверить ID записей, если они в одной строке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строка, которая через пробел содержит в себе ID записей:

```
var stringId = '155 200 10 19 15';
```

И есть массив, его перебор выполняю таким кодом:

```
$.each(array, function (index, value) {
   /*например что-то вроде:
   if (value.id == stringId) { .... }*/
});
```

Внутри перебора массива я хочу проверить, соответствует ли **value.id** одному из id которое есть в строке **stringId**

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант в jQuery есть [inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).
В случае если в массиве нет совпадений вернёт -1, в остальном больше -1.

Делаете из строки делаете массив и проверяете есть ли в массиве нужное значение.

```js
var stringId = '155 200 10 19 15';
var res = stringId.split(/ +/);

console.log($.inArray( "200", res ));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вариант с indexOf:

```js
var stringId = '155 200 10 19 15';
var res = stringId.split(/ +/);

console.log(res.indexOf("200"));
```

Вариант с includes (возвращает true или false):

```js
var stringId = '155 200 10 19 15';
var res = stringId.split(/ +/);

console.log(res.includes("200"));
```

Comment: зачем жквери если в масива есть `indexOf` ?

Comment: Зачем `indexOf`, если есть `includes`? :)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Добавил в indexOf, правильно сделал?

Comment: @Yaant добавил вариант с includes, правильно сделал?

Comment: Правильно :) Хотя необходимости в регулярке для `split` я не вижу, результат будет тот же, если использовать обычный пробел. :)
Ну и для коллекции, еще слегка извращенный вариант без массива: `(' '+stringId+' ').includes(' '+200+' ')`

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо за инфу :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringId = '15 200 10 19 15'; //Ваша строка
var arr = [15, 300, 10]; //Массив по которому нужно пройтись, для проверки, есть-ли в stringId нужный вам id.

function splitStringWithNumbers(str) {
  var splittedStr = str.split(' '); //получаем массив из чисел, разделяя по пробелу с типом string пока ['15','200','10','19','15']
  return splittedStr.map(strNumber => parseInt(strNumber)); //переводим в тип number и возвращаем массив из id
}

var ids = splitStringWithNumbers(stringId); //[15,200,10,19,15]

arr.map((item) => {//можно воспользоваться с методом 'map', появившийся с ES6. проходится по каждому элементу массива (15, 300, 10)
  if (ids.includes(item)) { // с помощью метода includes  у массива, проверяем на совпадение id в ids
      console.log(item)//если есть, выводим в консоль
  }
}); //получим в результате 15, 10
```

Comment: постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы. [edit]

Comment: Спасибо, буду стараться!)

Comment: А если `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: добавил функцию, которая будет разделять строку по пробелам, и возвращать массив из чисел